# How to use an external domain in the From field when programatically sending email using Exchange Online?

Tags: c#, email, azure, office365, spoofing

Sending emails from Exchange Online on behalf of another user [seems to be possible](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-sending-email-on-behalf-of-another-user-in-Office-365-c5e7749d-244e-477f-998e-55d3876c22ec) from our own domains but what about sending an email with a from address in a completely external domain? Is this completely forbidden by Microsoft or are there some ways to achieve this programmatically?